# How to get remaining values except matches in JavaScript Regex Match

Tags: javascript, regex

String `${provider.name} - ${item.publication_time|date|relative}`
Regex `/\${([^}]+)}/gmi`

From `string.match(/\${([^}]+)}/gmi)` this, I am getting `["${provider.name}", "${item.publication_time|date|relative}"]` as output.

But I need other unmatched parts of the string in the output array. My expected result should be `["${provider.name}", " - ", "${item.publication_time|date|relative}"]`

Can you please suggest me how can I achieve this by changing the regex?

Comment: Use `s.split(/(\${[^{}]+})/i)`

Comment: In addition to Wiktor's answer, chain `.filter(s => s)` after the `.split` to remove empty strings